ActionScript 2.0: Input data from .swf file will not save variables correctly in a .txt file. Error: Undefined

I have a live chat system that I built in Flash CS6 using ActionScript 2. Everything works well except for one instance name/variable that keeps showing up as "undefined" inside of a .sol Shared Object file. Here is the code:

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Starts the action when user left clicks with mouse button:

on (release) {
if (UserName eq "") {
    _root.LiveChat.Status = "Please enter a user name.";
} else if (Message eq "") {
    _root.LiveChat.Status = "Please enter a valid message.";
} else {

// Creates the shared object in Flash CS6 Shared Object directory folder:       
var so:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("Chat.txt.sol");

// Sends the newly fresh input data from 3 textboxes called UserName, Message, and ChangeColorText to the .sol file in HTML format:         
so.data.User = "\r\n" + "<font color=" + ChangeColorText + ">" + UserName + ":</font> " + Message + " " + "<font color=" + "'#B4B65A'" + "><font size=" + "'13'" + ">" + "Posted: " + new Date + "</font></font>";
so.flush();
    }}

// All code above this line below works perfectly except ChangeColorText shows up in the .sol file as undefined.

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// I also tried this code to see if I can send variable data to a new Chat.txt file in the same directory folder as the .fla and .swf file but no avail:

on (release) {
if (UserName eq "") {
    _root.LiveChat.Status = "Please enter a user name.";
} else if (Message eq "") {
    _root.LiveChat.Status = "Please enter a valid message.";
} else {
    var UserName:String;
    var Message:String;
    var ChangeColorText:String;     
    var fileRef:String;
    textToSave = UserName +"\n" + Message +"\n" + ChangeColorText;
    fileRef = new String();
    fileRef.String(textToSave,"Chat.txt");
    so.flush();
}}

Please let me know of any mistakes I made dealing with my code that needs correcting.
UPDATE: I figured out the answer to my own problem. Turns out I forgot to root the path correctly in the .fla and exported .swf file, so the code for instance name/variable "ChangeColorText" is actually "_root.ChangeColorText"
Note: I realized that in ActionScript 2 when you create an instance name/variable in a button, you have to make sure that you make a path that goes straight to the source. Which in this case was the text box called "ChangeColorText."
My problem is solved.

As a side note, Flash is not supposed to save files THAT easily, so the thing you did with the fileRef bears no sense both in terms of language and the Flash Player capabilities.

Yeah I figured that out later with the code that has "FileRef" in it. That code was something that worked for AS3 and not AS2. So I fixed my code using the first code I posted instead adding the "_root.ChangeColorText" to it and it turned out fine. I'm now still figuring out coding to load the variables in the Chat.txt.sol file back up in the .swf file. If you have any pointers on this, please let me know.

SharedObject is a cookie-type thing. You can store the data and retrieve it in the next session.

Well I know that. I've been reading that you can retrieve the data instantly while the .swf file is still open. But in order to do it, you have to code it a certain way.

I was hoping that you might have some small sample code that would help with the way my .swf is setup.

Well, my AS2 is very rusty, I haven't used it since 2008, but the concept should be right so I believe you'll figure it.
// First of all, let's initialize a SO that is visible everywhere.
// Also, you don't specify file name here, just any String identifier.
_global.ChatSO = SharedObject.getLocal("My Chat");

// Now you need to set up data if it is the first time.
if (_global.ChatSO.data.chatLog == undefined)
{
    _global.ChatSO.data.chatLog = "";
    _global.ChatSO.data.userName = "";
    _global.ChatSO.data.messageCount = 0;
}

Then, the frame with the TextFields. Let's assume they have mnemonic and self-explanatory instance names UserName, UserInput and ChatLog respectively.
// Initialize.
UserName.text = _global.ChatSO.data.userName;
UserInput.text = "";

// If the cookie is not empty, the ChatLog TextField will display something now.
ChatLog.htmlText= _global.ChatSO.data.chatLog;

function sendMessage():void
{
    if (UserInput.text == "")
    {
        // The input TextField is empty. Don't do anything.
        return;
    }
    
    var htmlMessage:String = "";
    
    // Let's form the entry.
    if (_global.ChatSO.data.messageCount > 0)
    {
        htmlMessage += "<br/>";
    }

    htmlMessage += "<font color=\"#DEFACE\">" + UserName.text + ":</font> ";
    htmlMessage += UserInput.text + " ";
    htmlMessage += "<font color=\"#B4B65A\" size=\"13\">";
    htmlMessage += "Posted: " + new Date() + "</font>";
    
    // Add the new entry to the chat...
    ChatLog.htmlText += htmlMessage;
    
    // ...and record it as well.
    _global.ChatSO.data.messageCount += 1;
    _global.ChatSO.data.userName = UserName.text;
    _global.ChatSO.data.chatLog += htmlMessage;
}

Now you just call the sendMessage() function in the button on (release) handler, and that's about it.

The code you wrote is good but it still doesn't help with my setup for AS2. When you press the send message button for my .swf file, the code I already have setup works in sending a "UserName" and "Message" to the "Chat.txt.sol" file the way I want which is in "html format" in that file which looks like this:
LiveChat=Barbra Jones: Hey there everyone! Posted: Sun Apr 14 19:12:48 GMT-0500 2024

What I currently want it to do is when that same user "Barbra Jones" or any other user name sends another message, I want the old message to delete "LiveChat=" and the new message to show up at the top with the "LiveChat=" in front of the new message like this example:
LiveChat=Tiffany Baker: Hello Barbra, how are you today? Posted: Sun Apr 14 19:35:48 GMT-0500 2024

Barbra Jones: Hey there everyone! Posted: Sun Apr 14 19:12:48 GMT-0500 2024
Also, I want to get rid of (if possible) this that shows up in the "Chat.txt.sol" file as well because when the chat log box instantly loads back up the .swf file text for reading chat logs, it shows it which I do not want showing in it:
¿    TCSO        InstantLiveChat      User  í
If there was a way I can send a picture example on here I would so you can better understand what I'm talking about.

I solved my issue. Just needed to add "+" before the equal sign.
